# Animation.css and <forms>: Bug

Tags: css

I am using https://animate.style/, and  when i include

> link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

In the folowing code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head style = "background: black">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body style = "background: black" class = "animate__animated animate__backInDown animate_slower">
    <div style="position:absolute; left: 40%;">
      <h1 id = "" style="color:white">EXAMPLE</h1>
    </div>
    <button id = "about" style="position: absolute; right: 5%; top: 0%;" >About</button>
    <div class="scripts">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
        for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
          buttons[i].addEventListener("click", onButtonClick, false);
        };
        function onButtonClick(event) {
                    if(event.target.id === "about"){
                        window.location.href = "about.html";
                    }else{
              return;
            }
          }
      </script>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 24%; left: 1%">
      <form id = "">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Address" >
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get Very different positioning to if I did not include it.

It seems to only affect the "top" and "bottom" command, except when it is used with "buttons".

Does anyone know why this is an issue?

Cheers,

K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the cdn and using these classes `"animate__animated animate__backInDown animate_slower"` in the body loses an inherent property in the `<body>` tag that causes the percentage measure to be lost. Remember that the percentage measurements are taken from the parent component.

A solution would be this:

```
 <html style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  <head style="background: black;">
    <link
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body
    style="background: black; width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    class="animate__animated animate__backInDown animate_slower"
  >
```

[I'll leave you a codesandbox with your complete code](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-sun-k2krr?file=/index.html:16-364)